# Unending/non-terminating database query - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to implement a way of clicking a button and running a method without having to switch to the view of the specifid item/object found by id. I'm using PostgrSQL.

In my PaymentsController I have a method called withdraw, which looks something like this:

```
def withdraw
 @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
 @payment.withdrawn = true
 @payment.amount_interest = withdraw.amount * 1.1
 @payment.save
 head :ok
end
```

And the route:

```
  patch '/withdraw/:id', to: 'payments#withdraw', as: :withdraw
```

each statement with link_to:

```
<% @payments.each do |withdraw| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= withdraw.amount %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_path(withdraw), method: :patch, remote: true %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:** Upon clicking "Withdraw" I get an unending database query that looks like this:

```
Started PATCH "/withdraw/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-11 21:20:34 +0200
Processing by PaymentsController#withdraw as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Started PATCH "/withdraw/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-11 21:20:34 +0200
Processing by PaymentsController#withdraw as JS
Member Load (40.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Member Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Payment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Payment Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Payment Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Payment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

My Payments model has the following:

```
account:string amount:decimal paid:boolean withdrawn:boolean amount_interest:decimal

belongs_to :member
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can u add the complete request log, that is the part where the request starts to printing this line indefinitely and also share the src of your `Payment` model

Comment: @dexter I have added additional information

Comment: not sure what `head :ok` does but it's the only thing that sticks out

Comment: Is there another way to call the method without switching views, except for the implementation that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bug in my withdraw method.

changed:

```
@payment.amount_interest = withdraw.amount * 1.1
```

to:

```
@payment.amount_interest = @payment.amount * 1.1
```